# Can I just delete Chromium without hurting my Chrome application / program at all?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I get the basic premise that one can be added to or made custom from user to user.

I ask only because I am simply just an average user who views online videos, i.e.: Netflix or YouTube.

I have for some unknown reason both Google Chrome and Chromium.

This is a stand up machine, not a laptop, and it was assembled here at home.

It is fairly fast and has very much computing power but when I use Chromium it lags, and the same happens for my Chrome browser.

So if I'm not programming, can I just delete Chromium without hurting my Chrome application / program at all?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/202825/what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-chromium-and-chrome/) article out it goes through the differences of Chrome and Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium is open source and Chrome is closed source :)

A list of the differences is available here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/chromium_browser_vs_google_chrome.md

Note that if that isn't enough for you, a simple Google search for Chromium vs Chrome gives a ton of results.

As for the replacement, you can simply delete one of the two with apt or package manager. However, I've heard that chrome loses speed without Chromium, so on my laptop I keep both installed but I use Chrome. Thus, I would recommend you uninstall Chrome if you have to uninstall something.